# how to setInterval on redux action without re-rendering the whole app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have an app with redux and redux toolkit.

I try to have a background call to refresh my notifications in the background but every time it is called the whole app gets refreshed.

In my Notification slice I have the following `createAsyncThunk`:

```js
// Thunk is an async middleware for handling reducers
export const reloadNotifications = createAsyncThunk(
    'notifications/reload',
    async (userToken: string): Promise<Notification[]> => {
        try {
            const req = await axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT as string, {
                query: myNotifications()
            }, { headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${userToken}` } })
            // Check data exists before pushing
            if (req?.data?.data?.myNotification) {
                return req.data.data?.myNotification as Notification[]
            } else {
                return []
            }
        } catch (error) {
            return []
        }

    }
)
```

In my NotificationHeader component I have this:

```js
export const NotificationHeader: React.FC<any> = () => {
    const notifications = useSelector(s => s.notifications.notifications);
    const [seenNotification] = useMutation(SEEN_NOTIFICATION);
    const [location, setLocation] = useLocation();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const auth = useSelector(s => s.auth);
    const handleClick = (notification: Notification) => {
        seenNotification({ variables: { notificationID: notification.id } }).then(async ({ data }) => {
            setLocation(getUrlNotification(notification, auth.user.id))
        }).catch((e: any) => {
            setLocation(getUrlNotification(notification, auth.user.id))
        })
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setTimeout(
            () => {
                // Only get notifications if i'm logged in
                if (auth.isLogged) {
                    dispatch(reloadNotifications(auth.token))
                }
            }, 3000);
        // This handles componentUnmount to clear the timer
        return () => clearTimeout(timer);
    });
    return (
        <Menu placement="bottom-start">
            <MenuButton marginRight="10px" variant="secondaryAction" bg="brand.orange" color="brand.purple" as={Button}>
                {(notifications && notifications.length > 0 && notifications.length < 10 &&
                    <SmallBadge content={notifications.length} />
                )}
                {(notifications && notifications.length > 9 &&
                    <SmallBadge content="9+" />
                )}
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBell} />
            </MenuButton>
            <MenuList commandSpacing="sm" bg="brand.purple" color="brand.orange">
                {(notifications && notifications.length > 0) ?
                    notifications.map(notif => (
                        <MenuItem key={`notif-${notif.id}`} maxH={20} _focus={{ bg: "brand.orange", color: "brand.purple" }} className="notificationItem">
                            {(!notif.isSeen) ? <Badge marginRight={2} size="sm" colorScheme="green">NEW</Badge> : undefined}
                            <Link href="#" onClick={() => handleClick(notif)}>{notif.title}</Link><Text marginLeft={4} marginRight={2} textAlign="right" flex="1" color="brand.gray" as="i" fontSize="xs">{moment(notif.createdAt).format(`DD MMM YYYY`)}</Text>
                        </MenuItem>
                    ))
                    : (
                        <MenuItem isFocusable={false} textAlign="center" maxH={20} _focus={{ bg: "brand.orange", color: "brand.purple" }}>
                            You have no new notifications
                        </MenuItem>
                    )}
            </MenuList>
        </Menu >
    );
}
```

However with this the interval causes a full refresh of the app even non child components.

I have also tried to add the following middleware to cause the notification interval to be triggered but this caused the full app to crash

```js
export const updateNotificationsMiddleware: Middleware = api => next => action => {
    const updateNotifications = async () => {
        const { auth } = api.getState() as State;
        api.dispatch({
            type: 'notifications/reload',
            payload: auth.token
        });
        setTimeout(updateNotifications, 3000);
    };
    updateNotifications();
    return next(action);
};
```

How can I have a simple API call with redux that will refresh my state every x second without causing a full app refresh.

I have also tried the following from the answer below:

```js
let initialized = false
export const updateNotificationsMiddleware: Middleware = api => next => action => {
    const updateNotifications = async () => {
        console.log('in middleware')
        const { auth } = api.getState() as State;
        api.dispatch({
            type: 'notifications/reload',
            payload: auth.token
        });
        setTimeout(updateNotifications, 3000);
    };
    if (!initialized){
      initialized = true
      updateNotifications();
    }
    return next(action);
};
```

I have then updated my thunk to reflect the following:

```js
// Thunk is an async middleware for handling reducers
export const reloadNotifications = createAsyncThunk(
    'notifications/reload',
    async (userToken: string): Promise<Notification[]> => {
        console.log('in action')
        try {
            const req = await axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT as string, {
                query: myNotifications()
            }, { headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${userToken}` } })
            // Check data exists before pushing
            if (req?.data?.data?.myNotification) {
                return req.data.data?.myNotification as Notification[]
            } else {
                return []
            }
        } catch (error) {
            return []
        }

    }
)
```

The middleware console.log is indeed shown every 3 second which is awesome but the action is still never called. The `console.log` does not appear once and the network request also does not get triggered.

Comment: You probably have a selector high up in your component tree that selects a big chunk of your state - including your `s.notifications.notifications`. That will cause a rerender if that changes. You probably need to look for that useSelector call.

Comment: @phry if that was the case the issue would still be happening when the code is commented as other states are changed all through the app no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gave your middleware a re-read. You add a timer on every action happening, which probably causes your problem. I think getting it down to doing that only once should solve your problem:

```js
let initialized = false
export const updateNotificationsMiddleware: Middleware = api => next => action => {
    const updateNotifications = async () => {
        const { auth } = api.getState() as State;
        api.dispatch({
            type: 'notifications/reload',
            payload: auth.token
        });
        setTimeout(updateNotifications, 3000);
    };
    if (!initialized){
      initialized = true
      updateNotifications();
    }
    return next(action);
};
```

Comment: I have tried this and the middleware is never processed.
I have also tried calling in a `useEffect` the action once to morce the middleware to trigger and this caused a non stop spam to the api every millisecond almost.

Comment: The middleware will be processed as soon as the first action in your application is dispatched. With the `initialized` check above, `updateNotifications` should only get executed once and then every three seconds. Without that, you will get an action immediately after an action, which will trigger another action to be sent.

Comment: Without calling the action is never ever called once. even though many other actions are called all through the application from login to update profile and more

Comment: Then you did not register your middleware in your store? Every action will always go through every middleware.

Comment: From what I can see my bad the middleware is triggered but the api.dispatch is not calling the action properly

Comment: If the action shows up in the devtools, the action is triggered properly. Are you expecting any side effects to happen here? If yes, are you sure you have those hooked up correctly?

Comment: I have updated my question in integrating your answer

Comment: This is a basic misunderstanding. Dispatching a `'notifications/reload'` action will not magically trigger your thunk. You have to dispatch the thunk itself.

Comment: However I can't do that as doing `api.dispatch(reloadNotifications(auth.token))` causes the folowing message: `Property 'type' is missing in type 'AsyncThunkAction<NotificationBingo[], string, {}>' but required in type 'AnyAction'.`

Comment: Just because TypeScript doesn't know about it doesn't mean it is impossible. Sometimes you will have to do a manual type assertion because you know better `(api.dispatch as ThunkDispatch)(reloadNotifications(auth.token))`